# How do you make the height of a Dojo DataGrid change based on it contents

Tags: datagrid, height, dojo

I understand that in order for the grid to display the parent div needs a specific height.  Now I would like the grid to shrink or grow in height depending on the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

The following will give the grid a max height of 300px but will shrink it if there are only a couple of rows displaying.

Parent div

```
var divGrid = domConstruct.toDom("<div id='divGrid' style='height:300px;'></div>");
domConstruct.place(divGrid, dojo.byId('Contents'));
```

Create grid

```
var grid = new DataGrid({
   id: 'grid',
   store: store,
   structure: layout,
   style: "height:300px",
   loadingMessage: "Loading...",
   noDataMessage: "No data...",
   selectionMode: 'single',
   rowSelector: '20px'
});
grid.placeAt(divGrid);
grid.startup();
```

Now after the grid is loaded

```
dojo.connect(grid, '_onFetchComplete', function() {
   var list = query('#grid .dojoxGridContent');
   var height = list[0].offsetHeight + 25;  // additional 25 to account for headers
   if (height < 300) {
      dojo.byId("divGrid").style.height = height + 'px';
      dojo.byId("grid").style.height = height + 'px';
      grid.resize();
      grid.update();
   }
});
```